# How should a function be applied by row on a dataframe to generate a new or expanded dataframe in r

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, rowwise

I am trying to expand an existing dataset, which currently looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(
        site = letters[1:3],
        years = rep(4, 3),
        tr = c(3, 6, 4)
)
```

tr is the total number of replicates for each site/year combination. I simply want to add in the replicates and later the response variable for each replicate. This was easy for a single site/year combination using the following function:

```
        f <- function(site=NULL, years=NULL, t=NULL){
                df <- tibble(
                        site = rep(site, each = t, times= years),
                        tr = rep(1:t, times = years),
                        year = rep(1:years, each = t)
                        )
                df 
        }

# For one site:
f(site='a',  years=4, t=3)

# Producing this:
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
# site     tr  year
# <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 a         1     1
# 2 a         2     1
# 3 a         3     1
# 4 a         1     2
# 5 a         2     2
# 6 a         3     2
# 7 a         1     3
# 8 a         2     3
# 9 a         3     3
# 10 a         1     4
# 11 a         2     4
# 12 a         3     4
```

How can the function be applied to each row of the input dataframe to produce the final dataframe? One of the apply functions in base r or the pmap_df() in the purrr package would seem ideal, but being unfamiliar with how these functions work, all my efforts have only produced errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to apply the same function, use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
pmap_dfr(df, ~ f(..1, ..2, ..3))
# A tibble: 52 x 3
#   site     tr  year
# * <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 a         1     1
# 2 a         2     1
# 3 a         3     1
# 4 a         1     2
# 5 a         2     2
# 6 a         3     2
# 7 a         1     3
# 8 a         2     3
# 9 a         3     3
#10 a         1     4
# … with 42 more rows
```

---

another option is `condense` from the devel version of `dplyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
      group_by(rn = row_number()) %>% 
      condense(out = f(site, years, tr)) %>% 
      unnest(c(out))
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can also use `do.call` with `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, c(f, unname(as.data.frame(df)))))
```

Comment: never known how to use `pmap`. Have seen it, and now curious as to when it will take a vector instead of a value when given a dataframe.

Comment: @Onyambu you can pass a named data.framed as the function parameters, and just apply `f` i.e.  here the 'tr' and 't' differ `pmap_dfr(set_names(df, c('site', 'years', 't')), f)`

Answer (score 1):

well in base R, you could do:

```
do.call(rbind,do.call(Vectorize(f,SIMPLIFY = FALSE),unname(df)))
# A tibble: 52 x 3
   site     tr  year
 * <chr> <int> <int>
 1 a         1     1
 2 a         2     1
 3 a         3     1
 4 a         1     2
 5 a         2     2
 6 a         3     2
 7 a         1     3
 8 a         2     3
 9 a         3     3
10 a         1     4
# ... with 42 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$site), function(x){
    with(x, data.frame(site,
               years = rep(sequence(years), each = tr),
               tr = rep(sequence(tr), years)))
}))
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` to apply `f` to every value of `site`, `years` and `tr`.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(f, df$site, df$years, df$tr))

# A tibble: 52 x 3
#   site     tr  year
# * <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 a         1     1
# 2 a         2     1
# 3 a         3     1
# 4 a         1     2
# 5 a         2     2
# 6 a         3     2
# 7 a         1     3
# 8 a         2     3
# 9 a         3     3
#10 a         1     4
# … with 42 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Akrun's answer worked well for me, so I modified it to make the function to be applied to each row of the dataframe a little more explicit:

```
        df1 <- pmap_df(df, function(site, years, tr){
            site = rep(site, each = tr, times=years)
            year = rep(1:years, each = tr)
            tr = rep(1:tr, times=years)
          return(tibble(site, year, tr))
          })
```